# Access field from a related UserProfile model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am having some trouble in selecting data in Django.

**models.py**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    my_location = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES)
    update_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField()


def __str__(self):
    return self.my_location

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    user_base = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES)
    user_position = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    user_phone = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.user)
    super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    locations = Location.objects.order_by('-update_date')
    context = {'locations': locations}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

I was able to show the `email` from `User` module but what I really want to show is the data from `UserProfile`.

Please, any advice.

Thank you.

Comment: So what isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use a OneToOneField

To make it more *direct*, I'd make the `UserProfile` have a `OneToOneField` relationship with `User`, instead of a `ForeignKey`. Because this will mean that a given user can only have one profile.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

In which case you can access it easier with `location.user.userprofile.your_field`

### Using a custom MyUser model

If you want to make this even more direct, you could make a custom `MyUser` model that will contain both the fields from `User` and `UserProfile`.

It would go roughly like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    # Adding your custom fields
    user_base = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES)
    user_position = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    user_phone = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Location(models.Model)
    user = OneToOneField(MyUser) # Using your custom MyUser model
```

This allows a more direct access, e.g. `location.user.user_phone` instead of `location.user.userprofile.user_phone`

I've only provided *pseudocode*, please refer to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

### Using a ForeignKey means you may have multiple profiles

In the other case where a user may have multiple user profiles, you then have the burden on you to select which profile to use to pull the relevant data from, because then the relationship would be   `user.userprofile_set`, a set that you will have to filter/index to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

use:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

[One-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#ref-onetoone) suit better your case. If you use them, your `User` model will automatically get a `userprofile` attribute that you can use like this:

```
>>> user = User.objects.get(...)
>>> user.userprofile.user_phone
12345
```

You can also consider [writing a custom `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model), so that you can get rid of `UserProfile`.

---

**Bonus tip:** `PositiveIntegerField` is not the right field for a phone number. Leading zeroes have a meaning. Also, `PositiveIntegerField` have a maximum value. Use `CharField` instead.

Comment: That would only matter if the op didn't want multiple profiles (which may be the case)

Comment: I changed it from onetoone to foreignkey seconds before posting cause i thought it is useless. I will give it a try and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: @marwanh-sleiman: that will work. However I strongly recommend you to consider writing a custom `User`, which will give you much more flexibility and performance

Comment: It worked. I gave your answer an Upvote but I have to give user @bakkal the correct answer flag because he gave me a full answer which will be useful for future beginners like me. Sorry